# Shorthand of checking the nullability of a bool variable used in an if condition

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

```dart
Future<bool?> f() async => true;

void main() async {
  final proceed = await f();
  if (proceed) {...} // Error
  if (proceed != null && proceed) {...} // Works but too verbose
}
```

Is there any shorthand or a better way of proceeding instead of writing a long `proceed != null && proceed` check? I know I might be missing something so trivial.

**Note**: I know a default value can be provided to `proceed` but that's just not my use case. Bang operator can do the trick iff `bool` is actually not `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a case where you can use the `??` operator which are documented here in the language tour:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions

It will allow you to rewrite your long if-statement into:

```
if (proceed ?? false) {...}
```

`??` means here that we want to use the value of `proceed` as long as it is not `null`. In case of `null` we want to use `false` as the value.

One drawback of this is that it does not seem like Dart makes any type promotion of `proceed` compared to the following where `proceed` afterwards is promoted to a non-nullable type:

```
if (proceed != null && proceed) {...}
```

Not sure if there are a Dart issue on that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But I was already aware of the `if (proceed ?? false)` part and I mentioned that in the post also, "I know a default value can be provided to proceed". I think I should go with the `if (proceed != null && proceed)`.

Comment: I do find `if (proceed != null && proceed)` easier to read, but `if (proceed ?? false)` is probably what most people are going to be using, even for booleans. It's recommended over `proceed == true` because the latter looks like a mistake. It works just as well as `(proceed != null && proceed)` because `proceed ?? false` really means `(proceed != null ? proceed : false)`.

Comment: @lrn What do you say about the missing type promotion of `proceed` to non-nullable after `if (proceed ?? false)`? Is this something which should happen? I can understand if the scenario is a little too odd for the analyzer.

Comment: I think it should work, and I'll file bugs to figure out why it doesn't work precisely the same as `(proceed != null ? proceed : false)`.